# SessionFactory bean not defined (No such bean) when switching from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to MVC web flavor context implementation

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up Hibernate to run through Spring to manage transactions in a simple web application. I have gone through the Spring tutorials and documentation and managed to set up a working toy example using and XMLApplicationContext referencing the xml file where my beans were defined. Now, I'm switching into Spring MVC and have used the exact same code and bean definitions. I have linked the xml file where my beans are being declared through web.xml, but I've been getting some weird behavior.

For reference here is a paste of my test example that was working: http://pastebin.com/gRCBhyiT

And here is the relevant pieces of my code:

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0/xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.base.package" />

    <bean id="defaultTemplateResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine"
          class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="defaultTemplateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.html,*.xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/time_tracker"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>my.package.TestData</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props></property></bean>

    <bean id="testDataDAO" class="my.package.HibernateTestDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

application.properties :

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/views/
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
#spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/time_tracker
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Application Main :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MainController.java :

```
@Controller
public class MainController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    private HibernateTestDao dao;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    //@Autowired
    public void setDao(HibernateTestDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.sessionFactory = factory;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "testing!");

        System.out.println(context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
        List<String> beans = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : context.getBeanDefinitionNames())
            beans.add(s);

        Collections.sort(beans);
        for (String s : beans)
            System.out.println(s);

        //dao.loadEntries();

        return "test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboard() {
        return "dashboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/view", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit() {
        return "view_as_form";
    }
}
```

HibernateTestDao.java :

```
public class HibernateTestDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TestData> loadEntries() {

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<TestData> items = session.createQuery("from TestData").list();
        return items;
    }
}
```

TestData.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class TestData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String value1;
    private Date value2;

    public Date getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(Date value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Initially after the switch I was getting this error:

```
DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE.
```

Which I fixed by adding fields to my application.properties file. After this  though, I managed to get all the way through testing and now when I'm trying to inject my SessionFactory bean into my test class I get a no such bean defined exception. I've been reading through as much documentation as I can find, but I cannot find the reason why this is happening.

The previous data source creation exception is maybe giving a clue as to why this is happening? I thought it was weird that I was getting that error since I have that information defined in the bean itself and not in an external config. Is there a servlet context being created that doesn't have all of the beans? Is applicationContext.xml not being read? (It seems to be read as templateEngine and defaultTemplateResolver beans show up when I print all of them out)

I am at my wits end trying to get this figured out. Any help or direction provided will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've created a SpringBoot Application and not a traditional SpringMVC appl. Spring Boot doesn't use Web.xml essentially ignoring all of your config in applicationContext.xml. Please read the Spring Boot documentation, its all JavaConfig in spring boot. Although u can import xml config but if u creating new app u shouldn't. Here is [sample app](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream/tree/dataJpa) on Spring Boot with Spring Data Jpa.